# Mobile web framework for existing javascriptMVC web site

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, ember.js, javascriptmvc

I have a quite complex web site developed with javascriptMVC and jQuery as main libraries, making use of a JSON API. Now i'm in the process of facing mobile web development, and have to make a decision on the framework to be used. The more mobile phones i can cover, the better.

As the web site has been developed with javascriptMVC, i guess it makes more sense to keep using same framework. I've looked at other options like backbone.js or ember.js, that would really love to play with, but can't find a big benefit over using a framework that developers already know.

That said, i'm thinking on javascriptMVC + jQuery Mobile. Don't pretend to open a long discussion about this. Based on your experience, is this a right approach or what do you think there could be best solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you are in client side MVC, look at here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/cross-device/#toc-mvc, you will get some idea.